# Как в yandex mapkit отображать иконки

Tags: flutter, yandexmapkit

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста как в yandex.mapkit на месте placemark отображать svg с сервера?

Comment: Не работал с yandex mapkit. Но взглянув на библиотеку, и на их примеры, которые они там дают, становится понятно, что вы можете вставить бинарную иконку. А значит вы можете перевести картинку из интернета в бинарный формат и вставить в placemark

Answer (score 0):

В MapKit нет поддержки SVG и flutter.